# SVN for PHP development in NetBeans under Windows?

Tags: php, svn, netbeans

Im using NetBeans under Windows for PHP development.

Now im controlling versions manually (simple copy project directory with date and time).

I feel that i need something better, something that will track changes.

**I want to consult here with experienced PHP developers who work alone (not in team)**.

I assume, that I need to learn a lot about SVN, SVN integration with IDE, using SVN etc.

Things I want to know:

- how much time may take learning SVN, and is it worth to spend time for learning in my case? SVN is not so simple, and im worrying that i will need to spent a lot of time, before i get benefits in productivity.
- im wondering how many professional PHP developers are using SVN and how effective it is.

Comment: This is not the proper place for this question. This sort of question is better suited for [chat]. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: Some projects I work alone, some not, but for every project [GIT](http://git-scm.com/) is my best friend. (Maybe not a SVN, but more!) Also Netbeans and GIT work nicely together, in my netbeans IDE I even see changes that I did years ago! :D Just by looking at the `Companies & Projects Using Git` of git's webpage you can see its professional, (Google, Facebook, Microsoft, Twitter, etc.)

Comment: SVN is simple as piss, but if you work alone, almost any VCS will do (although I wouldn't go CVS...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN is not that complicated to learn. The manual [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) is an excellent, free resource. There are many tools out there to make the day to day developer-level stuff easy and non-intrusive.

If you haven't used any sort of Version Control before, and you will always be working alone, then you can pretty much choose any VCS, be it SVN, Git (many people prefer Git, but say the learning curve is a little steeper than SVN) or any other.

The important thing is that you choose a system, and use it. Version Control can be as simple as you wanna make it, but it's imperative that you have something in place if your code is even vaguely important to you.